# Set top level element node for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below page layout:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="main-content profile0">
        <div class="messages">
        </div>
        <div class="moreinfo">
        </div<
    </div>

    <div class="main-content profile1">
        <div class="messages">
        </div>
        <div class="moreinfo">
        </div<
    </div>

</div>
```

Currently I have been doing things like

```
$('.messages').remove();
```

but I need to be able to set which div is actually the parent, so I can tell jquery to only look at the childer of the div "main-content profile1"

So that then

```
$('.messages').remove();
```

refers to the child of "main-content profile1" and not "main-content profile0"

Comment: when you remove messages class on click event ????

Comment: Please add your current JS code. We need to see what event you're running your code under

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) like

```
$('.main-content.profile1').find('.messages').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

As AmmarCSE said, you can use find(), but you could also just change the selector.

```
$('.main-content.profile1 .messages')
```